# Why did my answer become a Community Wiki after one edit?

Tags: bug, status-norepro, specific-question, community-wiki

I answer this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2929331/c-mode-in-visual-studio-2010-professional/2929355#2929355) originally entering just the following:

> Tools > Import and Export Settings >
>   Reset all settings > No, just reset
>   settings, overwriting my current
>   settings > Take your pick!

I then immediately edited to change the answer to:

> Tools > Import and Export Settings >
>   Reset all settings > No, just reset
>   settings, overwriting my current
>   settings > Take your pick! (i.e.
>   Visual C# Development Settings) >
>   Click Finish

And then the answer become a Community Wiki? I can't see what conditions I met to have this happen? I thought you needed about 10 edits for the answer to become a wiki entry?

Can anyone explain to me why this happened? I definitely didn't click it to be a wiki.

Comment: PEBCAK or 1d-10t error.

Comment: Seat to Keyboard interface bug apparently. I still stand by the fact I never checked the box.

Comment: the threshold is 8 edits (9 items in the revision list), not 10 edits. The 7 ways a post can become community wiki is in http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts-on-stack-overflow/11741#11741, near "How does a post become a Community Wiki post?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You definitely must have click it to be a wiki, at least accidentally

Comment: I thought that before I posted, but I always press TAB TAB enter to save. I thought maybe the TAB had skipped to the CheckBox, but the CheckBox isn't in the tab order.

Comment: You're right about that (just tried it), but unless there's a weird bug that only happened to you (as I recall, nobody ever had this problem) then you must have click it by accident.

Comment: Yeah guess so. But in a year of editing answers I've never done it before and my hand was no where near the mouse. Never mind, just one of those things.

Comment: I suggest you try to reproduce it again and update your question with details, try it with answers to this question @gen